# How to Import Excel file into mysql Database from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Lets say,
i want to import/upload excel file to mysql from PHP

My HTML is like below

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

PHP code is like below

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
    //First we need to make a connection with the database
    $host='localhost'; // Host Name.
    $db_user= 'root'; //User Name
    $db_password= '';
    $db= 'product_record'; // Database Name.
    $conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        //$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1 ";
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            //print_r($emapData);
            //exit();
            $sql = "INSERT into prod_list_1(p_bench,p_name,p_price,p_reason) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
?>
```

Excel file is like below

[image: excel file picture]

I want to import only the 2nd row values into my table. Please help me how can i solve it or give me any resource. I was able to upload the  excel file but it is  not correctly formatted. i want to upload 4 column in mysql's 4 column but it is uploading all 4 column in mysql's 1 column. am i missing something ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For >= 2nd row values insert into table-

```
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
//$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1 ";

$count = 0;                                         // add this line
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    //print_r($emapData);
    //exit();
    $count++;                                      // add this line

    if($count>1){                                  // add this line
      $sql = "INSERT into prod_list_1(p_bench,p_name,p_price,p_reason) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')";
      mysql_query($sql);
    }                                              // add this line
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thx. Had to convert from XLS to CSV and bam. Perfect.

Comment: stored data all are symbols how to get exact data

Answer (score 3):

You are probably having a problem with the sort of CSV file that you have.

Open the CSV file with a text editor, check that all the separations are done with the comma, and not semicolon and try the script again. It should work fine.